# Mockito.mockConstruction provides null logger in the tested class

Tags: mockito

I want to test the method Utility#fromJson. In order to do that I need to  mock the LoggerBean constructor which has some JNDI code in it.:

```java
    public class Utility {

       private static Logger log = LoggerBean.getLoggerBean().getLogger(Utility.class);
       private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

       public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> type) {
           try {
              return mapper.readValue(json, type);
           } catch (IOException e) {
             //during test log is null here
             log.error("json deserialization failed", e);
           }
        return null;
      }

    }
```

In the following test class I can mock the constructor with mockito and want that mocked Logger should be present in the Utility class. However the log in the Utility class is null during the test.

```java
    class UtilityTest {

    @Test
    void testFromJson() throws Exception {
        // mocking constructor
        try (MockedConstruction<LoggerBean> mocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(LoggerBean.class, (mock, context) -> {
            // further stubbings ...
            when(mock.getLogger(getClass())).thenReturn(Logger.getLogger(getClass()));
        })) {
            // the logger here works
            // Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
            //logger.info("-----------------");
            String json = " {\"key\":\"k1\",\"value\":\"v1\"}";
            assertNotNull(Utility.fromJson(json, Tuple.class));
        }
      }
    }
```

I am using mockito-inline version 3.11.2.
Please suggest how to get the mocked log in the Utility class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally realized that there is no need to mock the constructor of *LoggerBean* so that the following works:

```java
   private static Logger log = LoggerBean.getLoggerBean().getLogger(Utility.class);
```

So Mockito.mock(LoggerBean.class) already skips the call to the constructor.

```java
 class UtilityTest {

   private static Logger log = LoggerBean.getLoggerBean().getLogger(UtilityTest.class);

  @Test
    void testFromJson() throws Exception {
        try (MockedStatic<LoggerBean> mockedStaticLoggerBean = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggerBean.class)) {

            LoggerBean loggerBeanMocked = Mockito.mock(LoggerBean.class);
            when(loggerBeanMocked.getLogger(Utility.class)).thenReturn(pp);

            mockedStaticLoggerBean.when(() -> LoggerBean.getLoggerBean()).thenReturn(loggerBeanMocked);

            String json = " {\"key\":\"k1\",\"value\":\"v1\"}";
            assertNotNull(Utility.fromJson(json, Tuple.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Utility#fromJson will get the logger from UtilityTest class.

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer: don't even try.

If you really absolutely want a **static method**, then why not create a small utility class that does the same thing in a *non static* way (where you then can use the ctor of that class to insert your dependencies). And then maybe and keep a static instance of that class for your static method.

Remember that `static` comes with a lot of disadvantages. Especially in this case: if you can't test this static utility code without doing all this extra work, then you just introduced something that will interfere with unit testing any of the code that is going to *use* the static method.

In other words: you created hard to test code. Now you are facing the consequences of that, and your answer is to reach for the biggest hammer in the toolbox. But hammering a *screw* into the wall, yes that is possible, but is rarely a good idea. Instead you pick up a nail, or you go with the screw, but a screwdriver.

The real solution: step back, and remember to only only only ever use `static` for production code when doing so does *not* interfere with your ability to do proper, decent, *simple* unit testing.

---

<sub>Other readers: do not see this answer as discouragement to give the correct technical answer please!</sub>

Comment: Yes I can do that, but the ideas was just to play with mockito new capabilities. Where I fail to understand why log is null in the Utility class.

Comment: That is a valid use case ;-) ... my thoughts then: A) go step by step: ensure that your basic setup works, like just doing ordinary mocking B) then research all the howtos and existing questions that you can find on this C) if that still doesnt work, try the mockito mailing group https://groups.google.com/g/mockito?pli=1 ... then self-answer your question with the perfect technical explanation ;-)